# ggplot2 choropeth ZIPs / ZCTAs in Linux

Tags: ggplot2, choropleth, choroplethr

I would like to build a choropleth map in ggplot2 using ZCTAs (ZIP code tabulation areas, a rough analogue to the geographic boundaries of ZIP codes).  I've build choropleth maps in ggplot2 using the the state and county datasets, but I am having a really tough time finding any reprex from someone that has done this.  Also I'm on a Linux machine and I was unable to install choroplethr, so I don't think this is an option.

I found this JSON file for ZCTAs, maybe it will be of use.
https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/zip-codetabilation-area-boundaries/resource/ea476dcb-4846-4242-9fb3-d41afb13bf52

Comment: You might consider creating a separate question about your choroplethr installation problems.

Comment: @Ari is there anything special I need to be aware of when trying to install choroplethr on CentOS ? (Since I have the man himself) .  I would much prefer to use your package if I can.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I only have a mac, so that is the only OS I can test myself. But if you post it as a separate question, others might be able to help.